# Azure DevOps - Skip Pre-deployment approval if redeploying to same stage on the same release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm curious to know if there is a way in Azure DevOps release pipelines to skip the pre-deployment approvals if I'm doing a redeployment (Attempt# 2, 3,...) to the same stage on the same release?

Right now, the pipeline requests for the pre-deployment approvals even if it's a redeployment attempt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it indeed isn't possible to skip approvals, even on a redeployment. This would make sense from a safety standpoint.

Lets say I approved your deployment (V1.0) from a week ago.
Then today I approved a new deployment (V1.2).

If you were able to redeploy a previously approved deployments, you would be able to redeploy the deployment from a week ago (V1.0). As an operator, I wouldn't want you to be able to still deploy the first version without my consent.

Comment: Although I agree with you, there are genuine situations when I just need to a do a redeployment and I wouldn't want the pipeline to wait for approval if the exact same release was approved previously. 

For example, if my previous deployment failed due to a permission issue on the target server, and I get that permission thing sorted out and want to do a redeployment. I wouldn't need to change anything here. I hope I'm explaining correctly.

Comment: I understand that specific situation and, as a developer myself, a familiar situation.
Having said so, I don't think that Azure DevOps has inbuild logic to bypass this. 

I can only guess at the reasoning for this, but my assumption is that these kind of "exceptions" have few use cases, but do add a security risk as described.